# Possible to Mix SNI and Dedicated IP SSL on Apache?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.2

I've reached the limit of available IP addresses on my Apache web server but increasingly need sites to run under SSL. I'd be comfortable with some of the sites running under SNI but a few of them need the backwards compatibility only offered with SSL on a dedicated IP.

So, is it possible to mix the two on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; for a given listener IP address/port combo, cert and SNI and name-based virtual host logic are distinct from other listeners

So, say you want `192.0.2.50` to be SNI, with `192.0.2.51` and `192.0.2.52` as dedicated IPs:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.0.2.50:443
<VirtualHost 192.0.2.50:443>
  ServerName snisiteone.example.com
  # SSL directives here for this site's certificate to be served via SNI
  # Note that this cert, the first configured, will be used as default
  # for clients that don't support SNI
</VirualHost>
<VirtualHost 192.0.2.50:443>
  ServerName snisitetwo.example.com
  # SSL directives here for this site's certificate to be served via SNI - different cert!
</VirualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.51:443>
  ServerName dedicatedsite.example.com
  # SSL directives here for this site's certificate
  # Dedicated IP, so this'll be the only cert on this listener, SNI not used
</VirualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.52:443>
  ServerName dedicatedsitetwo.example.com
  # SSL directives here for this site's certificate
  # Dedicated IP, so this'll be the only cert on this listener, SNI not used
</VirualHost>
```